# Predicting counts using mlr

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr

I am using the learner `regr.gbm` to predict counts. Outside of `mlr`, using the `gbm` package directly, I use `distribution = "poisson"` and  `predict.gbm`, using `type = "response"`, returns predictions on the original scale, however I note that when I do this using `mlr`, the predictions appear to be on the log scale:

```
     truth    response
913      4  0.67348708
914      1  0.28413256
915      3  0.41871237
916      1  0.13027792
2101     1 -0.02092168
2102     2  0.23394970
```

However, the "truth" is not on the log scale and so I am concerned that the hyper-parameter tuning routines in `mlr` will not work. For comparison, this is the output I get with `distribution = "gaussian"`.

```
     truth response
913      4 2.028177
914      1 1.334658
915      3 1.552846
916      1 1.153072
2101     1 1.006362
2102     2 1.281811
```

What is the best way to handle this ?

Comment: mlr doesn't do any processing of the predictions returned by gbm -- can you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Answer (score 5):

This happens because `gbm` by default makes a prediction on the link function scale (which is `log` for `distribution = "poisson"`). This is governed by the `type` parameter of `gbm::predict.gbm` (see the help page of that function). Unfortunately `mlr` does not offer to change this parameter by default ([it was reported](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2466) in the mlr bugtracker). A workaround for now is to add this parameter by hand:

```
lrn <- makeLearner("regr.gbm", distribution = "poisson")
lrn$par.set <- c(lrn$par.set,
  makeParamSet(
    makeDiscreteLearnerParam("type", c("link", "response"),
      default = "link", when = "predict", tunable = FALSE)))
lrn <- setHyperPars(lrn, type = "response")

# show that it works:
counttask <- makeRegrTask("counttask", getTaskData(pid.task),
  target = "pregnant")
pred <- predict(train(lrn, counttask), counttask)
pred
```

---

Be aware that when tuning parameters on count data, the default regression measure (mean of squared errors) will possibly overemphasize fit for datapoints with large count values. The squared error for predicting "10" instead of "1" is the same as the error of predicting "1010" instead of "1001", but depending on your objective you probably want to put more weight on the first error in this example.

A possible solution is to use (normalized) mean Poisson log likelihood as measure:

```
poisllmeasure = makeMeasure(
  id = "poissonllnorm",
  minimize = FALSE,
  best = 0,
  worst = -Inf,
  properties = "regr",
  name = "Mean Poisson Log Likelihood",
  note = "For count data. Normalized to 0 for perfect fit.",
  fun = function(task, model, pred, feats, extra.args) {
    mean(dpois(pred$data$truth, pred$data$response, log = TRUE) -
      dpois(pred$data$truth, pred$data$truth, log = TRUE))
})
# example
performance(pred, poisllmeasure)
```

This measure can be used for tuning by giving it to the `measures` parameter in `tuneParams()`. (Note you will have to give it in a list: `tuneParams(... measures = list(poisllmeasure) ...)`)